# Print all complete lines of file

Tags: files, grep, newlines

How do I print all complete lines of a file? By 'complete' I mean only the ones that end with newline character. `grep` treats EOF as line delimiter, so `grep '^.*$' file` will print the last line even if there's no newline at the end of file.

The whole problem comes from parsing log files: we need to somehow be sure that the last entry was completely logged - i.e. it ends with newline.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343062/what-does-this-mean-in-linux-sed-a-a-txt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach is to use `perl`:

```
perl -ne '/\n/ && print' file
```

If you just want to check that the last character of a file is a newline, you can do:

```
tail -c1 file | grep -q '^$' && echo yes || echo no
```

But the `-c` option is not POSIX, so it isn't portable.

Answer (score 1):

`read` (at least in Bourne shell) requires a line to be terminated with newline:

```
# /bin/sh -c 'echo -e "foo\nbar\c" | while read line; do echo $line; done'
foo
#
```

So you could use something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line
    do echo $line
done < logfile.txt
```